# Add Shadow and Corners to UIView except the Bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, shadow, rounded-corners

I want to add rounded corners to top left and top right and shadow around it except the bottom. There should be no shadow at bottom. 
I am able to achieve rounded corners as needed. But not shadow. I need a code where both is achieved . In below image look at the Diagnose view. It has top left and top right corner rounded and shadow around it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution :

clipsToBounds = true, makes corners round but shadow gets hidden.
so we can use 2 views one as container and the main view as its subview . Container will have clipstobound = false and the main view will have clipstobounds true.

```
let containerV = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width , height: 50))
containerV.clipsToBounds = false
containerV.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
containerV.layer.shadowOpacity = 1 
containerV.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -0.5, height: -3.0) 
/* since we dont want shadow at bottom */
containerV.layer.shadowRadius = 2
containerV.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: containerV.bounds, 
cornerRadius: 10).cgPath

let headerLabel  = UILabel()
headerLabel.frame = containerV.bounds
headerLabel.text = "Test Header"
headerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

headerLabel.clipsToBounds = true
headerLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        headerLabel.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
containerV.addSubview(headerLabel)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code.
Custom Method. **Swift 4.0**

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    customCornerWithShadow(myView: myView, cornerRadius: 20)
}

func customCornerWithShadow(myView:UIView,cornerRadius:CGFloat) {

    myView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    myView.clipsToBounds = false[enter image description here][1]
    myView.layer.maskedCorners = CACornerMask(rawValue: CACornerMask.RawValue(UInt8(CACornerMask.layerMinXMinYCorner.rawValue) | UInt8(CACornerMask.layerMaxXMinYCorner.rawValue)))

    myView.layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3098039329, green: 0.01568627544, blue: 0.1294117719, alpha: 1)
    myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0, height:-1)

    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: myView.bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
    myView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
    myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @IBOutlet var btnActive : UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


      //  btnActive.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 171, green: 178, blue: 186, alpha: 1.0)
        // Shadow and Radius
        btnActive.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        btnActive.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
        btnActive.layer.shadowOpacity = 2.0
        btnActive.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        btnActive.layer.masksToBounds = false
        btnActive.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use extension,

in Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.3.1

```
extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let color = layer.borderColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let color = newValue {
                layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
            } else {
                layer.borderColor = nil
            }
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var shadowOpacity: Float {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var shadowOffset: CGSize {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOffset
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowOffset = newValue
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let color = layer.shadowColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let color = newValue {
                layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
            } else {
                layer.shadowColor = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```